# cPanel - Change theme back from x2 to x3

Tags: cpanel

I was logged in in cPanel and realized that it is possible to change themes. I have changed it to the x2 theme, but I am unable to find the option to change it back.

Is there a way to change the theme back in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Themes can be user selected depending on server permissions. The themes change with some releases of cPanel upgrades.

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/changed-theme-cant-change-it-back.414071/

They suggest logging out and logging back into your cPanel, and if this does not work, create a support ticket with your host.

The Host may need to access WHM and "Modify Account" and manually set you back to x3.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the cpanel screen should be a switch theme drop down.

If for some weird reason it is not there, I'd suggest contacting your host and have them resolve it for you.